# Serverside css not working in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, firefox, google-chrome, server-side-includes

I am using asp.net4 and have CSS presented like this in the head tag.

```
<link href="/ReadCss.aspx?css=<%
=Server.UrlEncode("~/Interface.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is so I can process a few variables into the sheet before giving it to the browser.

This works in IE8, it does not work in Firefox 3.6 or Chrome 9.

In FireFox and Chrome, it is as if the stylesheet is not applied to the page. All styles and formatting are missing.

Checking the IIS log and I see the page is sent successfully to those browsers. I can even directly navigate to the Read.aspx address and see the css.

How can i get these to work in those browser?

thanks

**Additional**
This is what the render looks like.

```
<link href="/ReadCss.aspx?css=%7e%2fcss%2fInterface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: view source in the browser what the css link look like? may want to give the url relative to the web root.

Comment: @Dagon: I have edited my post to display the rendered version of the tag. Surfing to the address rendered, displays the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your page sets a Content-type of `text/css`. If your page is serving as something else like `text/plain`, Firefox will likely ignore it. Try setting `Request.ContentType = "text/css"`in your codebehind.

Comment: Success!
I modified the code to Response.ContentType
`Response.ContentType = "text/css";
Response.Write(css);`

Comment: Just a word of caution, make sure you validate what is passed in via the query string so users can't serve up files they're not supposed to, like your web.config.

Comment: so right, thank you for that reminder. I have added a constraint.